# How do I get the tint color from a sprite batch in HLSL

Tags: c#, xna, hlsl

All I want to do is be able to obtain the tint color from the sprite batch draw calls from inside the HLSL shader, in the pixel shader.

I asked something similar to this [before](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11897015/obtaining-the-tint-color-from-a-sprite-batch-within-a-hlsl-shader), and I was told to have a look at the stock effects for the spritebatch. I looked at these and they were puzzling, but it was apparent that the tint was being passed to the pixel shader with the COLOR0 semantic. However, I tried using this semantic by adding the color parameter as seen below, but it did not work.

```
float4 PixelShaderFunction(float2 texCoord : TEXCOORD0, float4 inputColor : COLOR0) : COlOR0
```

I assume I am missing something, probably something to do with the vertex shader? I have no experience with the vertex shader, but all I want to do is be able to get the tint color from the sprite batch.

Anyone have experience with this? Help is appreciated

edit: to be more specific about about why it did not work, inputColor was always 0, no matter what I set for the spritebatch tint color

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It gets passed through the vertex shader. Note the documenation for [semantics](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb509647(v=vs.85).aspx) and for input modifiers on [function arguments](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb509606(v=vs.85).aspx).

The basic process looks like this:

`[vertex buffer data] -> [vertex shader] -> [pixel shader] -> [output]`

The pixel shader only sees what comes out of the vertex shader. At each stage the data is interpreted depending on semantics.

Between the vertex buffer and the vertex shader, the vertex declaration maps binary data into input registers described by semantics.

Between the vertex shader and the pixel shader, outputs are passed to inputs described by matching semantic names. Again, note [this list of semantics](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb509647(v=vs.85).aspx). (There is also a blend step here, to get input values for pixels in-between vertices.)

Finally, the output of the pixel shader is passed into a fixed set of inputs (with semantics) for the remaining fixed portion of the pipeline: depth-test, blending, etc.

---

I think what is getting you confused in this case is the fact that **there there are two ways of outputting data from a shader**: You can return it and give your return value a semantic (or many semantics if you return a structure).

But you can also output a value by assigning it to an argument (or simply leaving it in an argument) with either the `out` or the `inout` modifier.

This is what the vertex shader for `SpriteBatch` is doing. Note that it has `inout` specified for all its parameters - and that it doesn't modify the colour or texture-coordinate parameters at all. Those parameters are simply passed straight through to the pixel shader (with appropriate blending).

Comment: so how do I get the color parameter (the tint) in my custom pixel shader?

Comment: I read everything you said, and through the links, but I still don't know what to do. I matched the COLOR0 semantic with a float4 parameter in my pixel shader like I said in OP, I don't know why this is not working. What am I missing?

Comment: Oh wow, it turns out the tint color was always 0 just because of some c# code that was defaulting to integer math instead of float math, I think I fixed it now. Thanks Andrew